# git rebase mixes commits

Tags: git

I have a very strange problem:
I have two separate branches and I am doing a simple `git rebase --onto branchA tagOnMaster`.
This is done via a script that used to work perfectly on my old 32 bit machine. Now I switched to a new 64 bit machine and it stops working correctly.
It looks like git mixes commits.
For example, I have two consecutive commits with the first commit changing files a and b and the second commit changing filec. Now, the rebase creates the first commit correctly, but the second commit contains the changes to file c and a **revert** of the changes in the first commit. This reverted changes however somehow are left behind on the disk and cause problems in the third commit.

I think some images will show better what happens:

First original commit which just changes a space:
[image: First original commit]

Second original commit which only adds two new files:
[image: Second original commit]

The first rebased commit - this one is correct:
[image: First rebased commit]

But now it is getting strange: The second rebased commit contains the reverse of the first rebased commit in addition to the two newly added files:
[image: Second rebased commit]

After that second commit the rebase failes to continue with this message:

> Database/Scripts/Versions/2.0.0/PKG_BODIES/normalinvoices.sql: needs update
>   You must edit all merge conflicts and then
>   mark them as resolved using git add

And a look at the local changes reveals that the change from commit 1 is there again:
[image: unstaged changes]

I **really** would appreciate any insights into this.
Is this a known bug? A *feature*?! Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible that the corporate anti-virus program somehow locks the files and thus messes everything up? But I can't see how an anti-virus program leads to a file being there *earlier* than it should...
**And most importantly:** How to get my rebase working again?

Comment: Can you post the script you used?

Comment: To reproduce the problem, I already discarded the script and now I am only executing `git rebase --onto branchA tagOnMaster` while on branch `master`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're using rebase --onto which i don't see necessity for. It would be helpful to see screenshot of "gitk --all &" and know what do you want as the result of this operation.

Rebase --onto is a command that performs a move of part of the branch to the new base.

from git-rebase docs:

Here is how you would transplant a topic branch based on one branch to another, to pretend that you forked the topic branch from the latter branch, using rebase --onto.

First let’s assume your topic is based on branch next. For example, a feature developed in topic depends on some functionality which is found in next.

```
o---o---o---o---o  master
     \
      o---o---o---o---o  next
                       \
                        o---o---o  topic
```

We want to make topic forked from branch master; for example, because the functionality on which topic depends was merged into the more stable master branch. We want our tree to look like this:

```
o---o---o---o---o  master
    |            \
    |             o'--o'--o'  topic
     \
      o---o---o---o---o  next
```

We can get this using the following command:

```
git rebase --onto master next topic
```

...

In your case the last value is omitted therefore HEAD is used by default. That is causing you problems. I think you have confused the syntax of "rebase --onto" with a shorthand used for simple rebase:

```
git rebase master topic
```

this last command actually means:

```
git checkout topic # switch to topic branch
git rebase master # rebase topic branch on master
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I am trying to achieve is actually very simple: I want to replicate all commits on `master` since `tagOnMaster` on the branch `branchA`. I don't see how this is possible with `git rebase master branchA`. In my case I am using `rebase --onto` to rebase all new commits from `master` on `branchA`, check out `branchA`, fast forward to `master` and then reset `master` to `origin/master`. If this can be achieved simpler, I would be glad if you could tell me. But I fail to see, how this introduces the strange problems I am experiencing, especially since it worked (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) perfectly several dozen times on a different machine.

Comment: BTW: The reason for all this is the usage of git-tfs. As git-tfs changes the branch that is synced with TFS, I am not doing the sync on my master branch as that would introduce a lot of problems with the remote repository..

Comment: git rebase master branchA - will give you all changes of branchA to become based on the tip of the master, which in turn includes tagOnMaster. I.e. in this case you take the master branch as upstream, and branchA as topic branch. To me this direction seems more logical. Otherwise I see some contradiction in your sequence. And before I could dig dipper i need to see "gitk --all" snapshots at least before your operations.

Comment: BTW Why don't you try to specify full command and see what will happen? like:
"git rebase --onto branchA tagOnMaster master"

Comment: I take the last thing back. I'm trying to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot explain this behavior that you're experiencing. I think I understand what you were trying to achieve and I think that you do everything correctly from git commands stand point. I think that fact that you moved to new machine makes the difference and this is a glitch that should not appear.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to investigate this issue. If the old computer is not yet decommissioned, I will test it on this machine with the same repository and see if that makes it work again.

Comment: So, on the old machine git already was uninstalled, so I installed the latest version that comes with GitExtensions - 1.7.10 - to test it. It resulted in the same error. Then I installed the previous version 1.7.9 and it started to work again! It looks like there really is a bug in 1.7.10 that is responsible for this behavior.

Comment: git 1.7.11 somewhat reduces the problem, but it still doesn't work correctly. However, I found out that `git checkout branchA` followed by `git cherry-pick tagOnMaster..master` is the command I should use as this does exactly what I want.